# google contacts hover not working with python selenium webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am interacting with **python selenium hover effect** first time & facing an issue.

**I want to select the first contact checkbox visible on hover.** Following code  is successfully passing the Hover section lines & not showing any error but:

- Hover effect is not visible
- Post hover effect, click is not working & exiting the code block

I am getting print message up to **Hover crossed** in try: block & after that i am getting **Something went wrong** from except: block. Any advise on what is wrong here is really appreciated.

**Note:** - Following is the part of code where i am getting error.

```
...
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
...

driver = webdriver.Chrome(webdriverpath)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://contacts.google.com')

wait20 = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

def hover(browser, xpath):
    element = browser.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
    hover = ActionChains(browser).move_to_element(element)
    hover.perform()
    time.sleep(1) 

try:
    print('Entered in try block')
    time.sleep(1)
    clink = wait20.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.ncJ6qe a')))
    clink.click()
    print('contact link clicked')

    time.sleep(3)
    cimg = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="XXcuqd" and contains(@style,"transform: translateY(0px)")]/div/div/div')
    print('cimg crossed')

    hover(driver, '//div[@class="XXcuqd" and contains(@style,"transform: translateY(0px)")]')
    print('hover crossed')

    cimg.click()
    print('contact image clicked successfully')

except:
    print('Semething went wrong.')
```

Comment: it seems odd that you would look for cimg before you hover over the element that should be making it visible.  shouldn't you call hover, find cimg, then cimg.click()?

Comment: Yes technically you are right. But i had seen some examples where solutions were provided with such pattern hence adjusted my code accordingly. Though i don't think that would make much difference considering found element is stored in cimg variable & can be clicked any given point of time once found successfully. Correct me please if i am wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First try to not use broad try/except.
To be able to troubleshoot more your code, you should be at-least logging the original error.

```
try:
    ..some code..
except Exception as e:
    print('Semething went wrong.')
    print("Caught Exception type {} with err.msg: {}".format(type(e), e))
```

By looking at your code you are using:

```
find_element**s**_by_xpath
```

Which selenium will return you a list of element.

Either change your code to use single element:

```
find_element_by_xpath
```

Or pass the index that you need while trying to click

For example in your code:

```
cimg = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="XXcuqd" and contains(@style,"transform: translateY(0px)")]/div/div/div')
print('cimg crossed')

hover(driver, '//div[@class="XXcuqd" and contains(@style,"transform: translateY(0px)")]')
print('hover crossed')

cimg[0].click()
print('contact image clicked successfully')
```

**EDIT:**
I have looked at your xpaths and they are confusing and returning multiple elements. From your print() statement I am assuming that you want to click on the contact image to enable the checkbox?

If so, you don't really need to hover over the element before clicking on it. You can simply use a JS script to click on it.

I have modified your xpath with css_selector and have tried it myself.

```
cimg = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.XXcuqd [role="checkbox"]')
```

As this code will return a list, don't forget to pass the index of the contact you want to click on.

In the below case, I will click on the first one using a JS script:

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", cimg[0])
```

Then your code can look like this:

```
print('Entered in try block')
time.sleep(1)
clink = wait20.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.ncJ6qe a')))
clink.click()
print('contact link clicked')
time.sleep(3)
cimg = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.XXcuqd [role="checkbox"]')

print('cimg crossed')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", cimg[0])
print('contact image clicked successfully')
```

**Optional**
You could verify if the checkbox is really checked by verifying the attribute:

```
if cimg[0].get_attribute('aria-checked') == 'true':
    print('contact image clicked successfully')
else:
    raise AttributeError("Fail to select the contact image")
```

Comment: Hi @Nic Laforge - Thank for the broad try/except suggestion. Now I know the exact error. It's the hover code which is not working as "Element not visible" exception is thrown. Though i had mentioned about this in my question. click event is not working because element needs click is hidden behind hover event.

Comment: Hi @techworld, I have answered based on what I could see at first sight. I have edited the answer and tested the code. Can you a try with my suggestion? Thanks

Comment: Thanks a million @Nic Laforge. That was simply amazing. You saved my life. Really!. Your edit code worked like a charm!